# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy ERROR (Spring Boot + React js)

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors, github-pages, render.com

I've been browsing Stack Overflow for a few hours trying to find a solution to my problem, but unfortunately, I haven't found it yet.

I recently started learning React and created a full-stack to-do application. The backend is written in Spring Boot, and the frontend is in React.js. I communicate between the layers using the Axios library.

Since this is a project for my studies, I successfully set up a backend server hosting on the render.com website. It seems that everything is working fine on the backend side. I made sure to include the `@CrossOrigin("")` annotation. When I ran my create-react-app project on localhost:3000, all AXIOS requests were executed correctly. The problem arose when I deployed the frontend project on GitHub Pages. The page is displayed, but it is not communicating with the backend (no Axios request is being made).

I receive an error message:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://**** hdmj.onrender.com/todos' from origin 'https://*********.github.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Even adding the line of code: `axios.defaults.withCredentials = false;` did not solve the problem. How to identify the issue and fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try `@CrossOrigin(origins = "your frontend host")` in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `Spring boot` on the backend, I feel there are many ways to configure `CORS`. I have described them below.

**Option 1: Method level CORS Configuration**

Spring MVC provides @CrossOrigin annotation that marks the annotated method or type as permitting cross-origin requests. For example,

```
@CrossOrigin
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public Employee getEmployeeById(@PathVariable Long id) { ... }
```

**Option 2: Global CORS Configuration**

To enable CORS for the whole application, use `WebMvcConfigurer` to add `CorsRegistry`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

    registry.addMapping("/api/**") //add your api endpoints here
      .allowedOrigins("https://example.com") //add your origin URL here
      .allowedMethods("GET", "POST")
      .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
      .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
      .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);

    // Add more mappings...
  }
}
```

Make sure you replace your URL's and endpoints properly in the above code snippet.

Hope that helps!