# I can't get my backend working with frontend in production but in local environment

Tags: python, reactjs, ffmpeg, fastapi, render.com

This is the frontend code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import fileDownload from 'js-file-download';

function HomePage() {
    const [url, setUrl] = useState('');
    const [filename, setFilename] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('https://api-lnp5.onrender.com/api/download', { url, filename }, { responseType: 'blob' });
            fileDownload(response.data, filename);
            console.log(response.data);  // handle the response as needed
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-screen overflow-hidden">
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold mb-6">Download Reddit video!!!</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="flex flex-col items-center">
                <label className="mb-4">
                    <div className="text-lg mb-4 inline-block">Video URL:</div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" value={url} onChange={(e) => setUrl(e.target.value)} required 
                            className="border px-3 py-2 rounded focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-300 w-96"/>
                    </div>
                </label>
                <label className="mb-4">
                    <div className="text-lg mb-4 inline-block">Filename:</div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" value={filename} onChange={(e) => setFilename(e.target.value)} required 
                            className="border px-3 py-2 rounded focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-300 w-96"/>
                    </div>
                </label>
                <button type="submit" className="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded hover:bg-blue-600">Download</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default HomePage;
```

This is the backend code using python fastapi:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException

from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from pydantic import BaseModel
import requests
import json
import subprocess
import os

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "https://videodownload-frontend.onrender.com",  # replace with the origin of your frontend
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

class Video(BaseModel):
    url: str
    filename: str


def get_unique_filename(filename):
    counter = 1
    base_filename, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    unique_filename = filename

    while os.path.isfile(unique_filename):
        unique_filename = f"{base_filename}({counter}){extension}"
        counter += 1

    return unique_filename

@app.post("/api/download")
async def download_video(video: Video):
    url = video.url
    filename = get_unique_filename(video.filename)

    url += '.json'
    response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Video not found")

    json_response = json.loads(response.text)
    video_url = json_response[0]["data"]["children"][0]["data"]["secure_media"]["reddit_video"]["fallback_url"]
    audio_url = video_url.rsplit('/', 1)[0] + '/DASH_audio.mp4'

    video_response = requests.get(video_url, stream=True)
    audio_response = requests.get(audio_url, stream=True)

    with open('video_temp.mp4', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in video_response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 * 1024):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
    if audio_response.status_code == 200:
        with open('audio_temp.mp4', 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in audio_response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 * 1024):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
        subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'video_temp.mp4', '-i', 'audio_temp.mp4', '-c', 'copy', filename])
    else:
        os.rename('video_temp.mp4', filename)

    return FileResponse(filename, media_type='application/octet-stream', filename=filename)
```

I deployed the fastapi by docker to Render. When I start the frontend development server, I could communicate with the backend without problems. But when I deployed both frontend and backend to Render, it shows always the CORS policy

[image]

Why is it? if I could communicate with backend when starting local development server, it should be not related to backend.

This is URL to my frontend: https://videodownload-frontend.onrender.com/

Thank you!

I tried reconnect and restart the web service, also I tried to add CORS in fastapi. The api works fine with local server opened up. What should I do to debug? thank you

Comment: What is Render in your context? render.com?

Comment: Yes, render.com

Comment: By searching the text of the error related to render.com I found these: https://community.render.com/t/no-access-control-allow-origin-header/12947/1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76478363. I think you need to explicitly specify the header mentioned in the error. And Render related issues I think are better published on their forum. Search for the missing header name on their community site for example, it will give you multiple results.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to familiarize yourself with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and then how to properly [configure CORS for fastapi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/).